# Cylon loyalty card abilities and the New Caprica detention location

Tags: battlestar-galactica, pegasus

If the Cylon loyalty card ability says "If not in the brig...", can the player then activate it when he reveals himself as a Cylon while in detention in New Caprica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Abilities that are affected by the brig are affected by the detention area. The [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Battlestar_Galactica/bsg_FAQ_1-1-1.pdf) covers this under Pegasus Expansion (page 2), **Brig, Sickbay, Detention Area, Medical Center**

If you don't like that answer, the [Pegasus Rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Battlestar_Galactica/BSG-Pegasus-rulebook-web.pdf) (page 14) states:

> As is the case with the Brig, players cannot use the reveal actions on loyalty cards while in Detention.